# Create a bitmap using double values instead of int Android

Tags: android, int, double, android-bitmap

In my code I need create a Bitmap using double values. It´s important use the correct value.

I´m using:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(int, int, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

... When i would need something like:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(double, double, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Everything I've trying to make the conversion ( possible ? ) Only returns the initial value or integer

How I can use double values ​​when creating the bitmap?

Comment: What about Casting ?

Comment: @MD Sorry, I do not know what you mean

Comment: Cast your `Double` value to `int` .

Comment: @MD 
But this does not hold decimals, for example : double myDouble = 10.4 when i cast the double value to int return 10 ...I need the complete value of 10.4

Comment: Used it as String then

Comment: @MD 
I've tried , the problem is that Bitmap.createBitmap not accept String. I am blocked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101773/discussion-between-m-d-and-miguelc).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but bitmaps are rasters of whole pixels.  You can't have fractions of pixels, so you can only have integer numbers of rows and columns in the parameters for createBitmap.

Having said that, you can rescale how the bitmap is drawn using float scale factors applied via Matrix drawBitmap methods, e.g.

[Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint))

```
Matrix matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
matrix.postScale(3.14f, 3.14f);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

However, when it comes to rendering this on screen, it will again draw only whole pixels, so you still don't get fractional pixels displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, convert double to int:

```
double myDouble = 10.4;
int myInt = (int) (myDouble);
```

Using (int) casts the double into an int

Comment: Hello, doing what you propose, the result is also just initial value. myInt = 10