# Is converting float to matrix and matrix to bitmap possible in android?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, android-camera

I already converted the data from onPreviewFrame to rgb which is an int array. Gaussian Blur uses float/double values and I wasn't able to find methods for converting float/double values to bitmap.

The only way I have in my mind is convert these float values into Matrix and then into a bitmap. But i am not really sure if this is possible.

```
public Bitmap getProcessedImage(byte[] image){
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    int rgb[] = new int[image.length];

    decodeYUV420SP(rgb, image);
    convertToGrayscale(rgb);
    applyGaussianBlur(rgb);

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(IntBuffer.wrap(rgb));

    return bmp;
}

public void convertToGrayscale(int rgb[]){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < rgb.length;i++){
        int R = (rgb[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
        int G = (rgb[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
        int B = rgb[i] & 0xff;
        int gray = (R + G + B )/ 3 ;
        rgb[i] = 0xFF000000 | (gray << 16) | (gray << 8) | gray;
    }
}

//Method from Ketai project!
void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp) {

    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {       int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0)
                y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0)r = 0;else if (r > 262143)r = 262143;
            if (g < 0)g = 0;else if (g > 262143)g = 262143;
            if (b < 0)b = 0;else if (b > 262143)b = 262143;

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
        }
    }
}

public void applyGaussianBlur(int rgb[]){
    int kernelWidth = 3, kernelHeight = 3;
    float darray[][] = new float[width][height];

    float matrix[][] = new float[kernelWidth][kernelHeight];
    float sigma = 3.0f;
    float sum = 0;


    for(int j = 0, ct = 0; j < width;j++){
        for(int m = 0; m < height;m++, ct++){
            darray[j][m] = rgb[ct];
        }
    }

    for(int x = -1; x < kernelWidth-1;x++){
        for(int y = -1; y < kernelHeight-1; y++){
            matrix[x+1][y+1] = (float)((1/(2*Math.PI*Math.pow(sigma, 2))) * Math.exp(-(Math.pow(x, 2)+Math.pow(y, 2))/(2*Math.pow(sigma, 2))));
            sum+=matrix[x+1][y+1];
        }
    }

    for(int x = -1; x < kernelWidth-1;x++){
        for (int y = -1; y < kernelHeight-1; y++) {
            matrix[x+1][y+1] = matrix[x+1][y+1]/sum;
        }
    }


    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++){
        for (int m = 1; m < height-1;m++){
            darray[j-1][m-1] = (darray[j-1][m-1] * matrix[0][0]);
            darray[j-1][m] = (darray[j-1][m] * matrix[0][1]);
            darray[j-1][m+1] = (darray[j-1][m+1] * matrix[0][2]);

            darray[j][m-1] = (darray[j][m-1] * matrix[1][0]);
            darray[j][m] = (darray[j][m] * matrix[1][1]);
            darray[j][m+1] = (darray[j][m+1] * matrix[1][2]);

            darray[j+1][m-1] = (darray[j+1][m-1] * matrix[2][0]);
            darray[j+1][m] = (darray[j+1][m] * matrix[2][1]);
            darray[j+1][m+1] = (darray[j+1][m+1] * matrix[2][2]);
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0, ct = 0; j < width;j++){
        for(int m = 0; m < height;m++, ct++){
            rgb[ct] = Math.round(darray[j][m]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this is one of your first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can see what you have tried and better understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.

Comment: oh my bad.. Matrix can only hold 3x3 float[]... sorry

Comment: Create a bitmap using double values ​​instead of int android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037358/create-a-bitmap-using-double-values-instead-of-int-android

answer to my question...